# Tautomerism in alkenes

Tags: organic-chemistry, tautomer

Why doesn't but-2-ene exhibit tautomerism like alkenols?
By transfer of 1 hydrogen from terminal CH₃ to the middle carbon and forming a double bond between the two?

Comment: Getting a proton off an oxygen is easy peasy. Getting it off a carbon is not usually quite so easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for tautomerism to occur, the enol must be deprotonated, so as to allow the negative charge to come down, kick the pi bond of the C=C bond, which will bond to a proton. Hydrogen atoms on oxygen are much more acidic than hydrogens on carbons because of the electronegativity differences between O and H. Thus, the deprotonation does not happen in alkenes.